# Adding listener for CTRL+A in keyPressEvent doesn't highlight any text anymore

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt5

I am writting a search feature for one of our widgets in PyQt. I want to be able to capture the CTRL+A event in order to say that all the matches in that text have been highlighted.

What I did is override the `keyPressEvent` method:

```
def keyPressEvent(self,event):
    if event.key() == (Qt.Key_Control and Qt.Key_A):
        # do something
    else:
        super(QPlainTextEdit,self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

This works partially because it does say I selected all my matches(that is supposed to be the **do something** part) but it doesn't highlight all my text. So I want to combine my functionality with CTRL+A's default behaviour, but without interfering with it, just supplementing it.

**EDIT:** I just commented all except this call`super(QPlainTextEdit,self).keyPressEvent(event)` and it doesn't highlight anything. This class does extend `QPlainTextEdit` but now I'm curious what else can it be.

Comment: then call the `super(QPlainTextEdit,self).keyPressEvent(event)` unconditionnally, before the `if`. Also, I'm curious how the `Qt.Key_Control and Qt.Key_A` can work

Comment: I should have mentioned, I did exactly that before I posted and it didnt work. I'm very confused as to why it didnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to do something if you press CTRL and A at the same time without the default behavior of QPlainTextEdit.

First, let me point out two error of you code.

The first error is:

```
if event.key() == (Qt.Key_Control and Qt.Key_A):
```

should be

```
if event.key() == Qt.Key_A and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
```

In python, Qt.Key_Control and Qt.Key_A may be understood as Qt.Key_A, so when you press A without CTRL, you will enter "dome something" block.

The second error is:

```
super(QPlainTextEdit,self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

should be:

```
super(yourEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

or:

```
QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

so the whole code is:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_A and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
        print "i am in do something block"
        # do something
    else:
        print "i am in the else block"
        QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

Edit:As ekhumoro mentioned, if you want to use the default behavior of QPlainTextEdit before your custom behavior.You can use the following code.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_A and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
        print "i am in do something block"
        # do something
```

Comment: Actually, the OP **does** still want the default behaviour: "I want to combine my functionality with CTRL+A's default behaviour, but without interfering with it, just supplementing it". So you need to get rid of the `else` block, and call `super(MyTextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)` before the `if` statement.

Comment: thank you guys for the answer and edits, however it still will not do the default behavior of CTRL+A: "select and highlight all". I tried placing the super call: before my code, after my code, after my code in a return statement. None of them got the default behaviour to work. As I said in my edit: commenting all my code and just having def keyPressEvent(self,event):  super(MyTextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event) will not work.

Comment: @limbo. That's because you're not using `super` properly. This is clearly explained in the answer - i.e. "The second error". If you follow the advice carefully, the code will work.

Comment: The answer says I should use
super(yourEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event). However in my case "yourEdit" extends QTextEdit. So isnt that the same thing? This code is written inside the editor(yourEdit) that extends QTextEdit.

Comment: I didnt used QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event) since I thought that it is the same as super(yourEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event). Let me know if I somehow misunderstood how super works in my previous comment.

Comment: @limbo.If your have tried my solution but it doesn't perform your expected behavior, it doesn't mean you are wrong, it means my answer are not correct.In Qt, something doesn't perform the behavior as you need, it's not Qt's bug, it means you have lost something to do or to say you need a workaround.I am not pretty sure what you really need, if you can explain your real purpose, maybe i can help you to make a workaround.

Comment: @jiahilegass. Your code is correct - the OP is just not following your advice correctly.

Comment: @limbo. No, it's not the same - that's why your code doesn't work. The first argument to `super` **must** be your subclass.

Comment: @ekhumoro you are correct, I found out about this when reading more about super. The answer works, sadly I no longer need it as I made an incorrect interpretation when reading the requirements.